# Incorrect result from NSJSON Serialization

Tags: objective-c, json-deserialization, nsjsonserialization

I have got a very strange issue when I trying to deserialize my json string, the code is this:

```
NSString *testString = @"{\"cash\": 99946.222300000000}";
//    NSString *testString = @"{\"cash\": \"99946.222300000000\"}"; //It's correct if I use this one
NSData *jsonData = [testString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error;
id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
NSLog(@"Convertion result is %@",error?@"false":@"true");
NSLog(@"Result data is\n %@",jsonObject);
```

And the result is :

```
2017-08-30 18:04:36.430 DAE[45557:2989692] Conversion result is true
2017-08-30 18:04:36.430 DAE[45557:2989692] Result data is
{
    cash = "99946.22229999999";
}
```

So can anybody tell me if I did anything wrong? and how to solve it?

Really appreciate for any help.

Comment: why not you use @"{\"cash\": \"99946.222300000000\"}" ? any problem in that sentence ?

Comment: when you fetch the data at that time you can use **[[jsonObject valueForKey:@"cash"] doubleValue]** so it will give you 99946.22230

Comment: What is the issue here? That `99946.222299999999` is appearing in quotes? It's printing this way, but it's actually an `NSNumber` instance, not a string. Do you want it to be a string?

Comment: @NiravKotecha This is not my choice, the data is come from backend, and all of the other platforms don't have this issue.

Comment: @ItaiFerber The issue is it's incorrect, the output result should be **cash = "99946.22230000000"**;

Comment: @NiravKotecha The double value is correct, but why? Can you explain it?

Comment: Alanc Liu, as @caiwb says max length of double is 16. so you can use %lf for getting double value.
or you can use %9f (it will give you first 8 letter perfect but last 9 decimal point will be +1 or -1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it’s not wrong, it’s correct.

So, why you got the incorrect result?

First, The json value will be converted to a NSNumber object by **NSJSONSerialization**;

Then, the **-description** method of NSDictionary generate the result by stringValue method.

You should resolve the json value by this way to get the correct string:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:%lf, [jValue doubleValue]]
```

**But** you should pay attention to the length of the value, the max length of double is 16, so if you get a number over than it, you will never get the correct result.

Tell your backend guy that they should convert all the numbers to string before they give them out, because it’s really hard to resolve them correctly if it’s big enough.

Answer (score 1):

use it as Your commented string

```
NSString *testString = @"{\"cash\": \"99946.222300000000\"}";  

NSData *jsonData = [testString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error;
id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData 
options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
NSLog(@"Convertion result is %@",error?@"false":@"true");
NSLog(@"Result data is\n %@",jsonObject);
```

Comment: The data is coming from backend, it's now a way to fix it.

Comment: can you show your Response format or  share your Api then i ll give you proper code . Thanku